# What is a best practice to pass props through react-router <Link />?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I use react-router4. I want to pass a several props to one of my form components to initialize state, via `Link` component. I found two ways to do it:
Pass it via `state`.

```
<Link to={{pathname:'/orders/', state:{prop1: 'p1', prop2: 'p2', prop3: 'p3'}}} />
```

And path it via query params by changing url to `/orders/:prop1/:prop2/:prop3`

```
<Link to='/orders/p1/p2/p3' />
```

React full of best practice and recommendations how to use it properly. I want to know is there any recommendation how to pass props via `<Link />` component.
When I should use query params and when state?

Comment: This is quite intriguing :) Thinking of it, I can say they are useful in different ways. Passing properties via urls is a pull strategy, while passing them through the state sounds more like push strategy. I can see myself using both depending on the component I am trying to pass those properties to. If my component is pure and has a defined number of properties that are always to be used in the view, I'd probably use the state object. I'd be very happy to hear more from other more experienced React users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It kind of depend on the type of app you are building and whether when navigating to the next component do you already have all the required `props`?

For example, if a app depend on a external api to fetch order detail. When on the `orders` page, I prefer to use a `<Link to='/orders/1235' />` and fetches the order number base on the `pathname` received. Reason is because in the `orders` page, I do not have all the detail about orderId `1235` yet.

For most cases where I use pass via `state` are usually to toggle the UI only.

`<Link to={{pathname:'/home/', state:{newUser: true} }}/>`

So in my component, I have something that check if is `newUser`, i will display a instruction banner.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought in similar way. In my case I need to pass initial state to a form it is not quite UI only.  But putting so much stuff to url path looks awkward but it's more explicit in other hand.